# Anybody with experience in Andrew Valums Ajax Upload (qq.FileUploaderBasic) script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

There are 2 versions:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic(); // not working

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader();
```

It is suppose that the basic version `FileUploaderBasic` only gives a button and validate the uploaded file. I only wants that. But I do not even get the button.

This is a terrific and beautiful ajax based file uploader. But there are no reference to this issue and I am tried all. This is the second time that I use it but the first time I used the `FileUploader` version that worked great.

ref: [Ajax Upload; A file upload script with progress-bar, drag-and-drop.](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently the two classes differ in their required options: for setting up a `FileUploaderBasic` you will need to provide a `button` option whereas for `FileUploader` you have to specify an `element`:

```
var uploaderBasic = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
    button: document.getElementById('file-uploader-basic')
});

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader')
});
```

`FileUploaderBasic` also doesn't seem to apply the default button styles and content, you have to set them up by yourself (if needed):

```
<div id="file-uploader-basic" class="qq-upload-button">Upload</div>
```

You can look at a working version at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ofexux/10/edit) (JSFiddle was down at the time of this post).

Comment: +1 This is the kind of things that make great this site. Thank you very much Julian. You are absolutely right. 1.- use `button`, 2.- add a suitable `class/style`. THX!